# How can I properly use a backend RESTFUL API with Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, rest, backbone.js

I have been playing with Backbone.js for the past 2 months and I have successfully completed most of the example applications out there. Now, I have come across a topic that I can't seem to grasp so easily. Whenever I start building an application I have no problems sorting out my Backbone.js code, but when it comes to the REST API, I get lost. I have read many articles, tutorials, etc. I also attempted to build several applications following guides and tutorials (using mongodb, node.js, express and backbone.js), but none of those have enlightened me. My main target is to develop small-to-medium data-driven single page applications. So, to cut to the chase, I recently came across ASP.NET Web API and I find it quite interesting. But I couldn't find any useful integration regarding Backbone.js + WEB API. Where would my Backbone.js code reside in the project if I use WEB API, considering that I am using grunt-bbb as my build tool.

Thank you!

Best Regards,

Comment: Per the FAQ, "Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."

Comment: I always recommend Ruby on Rails to beginners because it does a lot of the boilerplate work for you.  You can be up and running with a Restful back end in minutes.  Here's a tutorial, if you want to try it: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html  Side note: Any back end can be restful, you just have to build it so http requests (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE) can hit it and perform CRUD operations

Comment: @dmoss18 Thank you very much for your insight! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @BradM I have edited my question and made it less open-ended :)

Comment: What OS are you using? Windows? Linux? OSX?

Comment: @dmoss18 I am using Windows, but I have no problem using Linux as well

Comment: You can use either, but I recommend Linux for rails development